# SUMPRODUCT ignore row if blank?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following results excel doc:

```
CAR|CLASS|CLASS FINISH POSITION|
1  |5    |1                    |
2  |1    |1                    |
3  |2    |2                    |
4  |     |                     |
5  |3    |3                    |
6  |5    |2                    |
7  |     |                     |
8  |2    |5                    |
9  |5    |                     |
10 |5    |8                    |
```

I am trying to calculate their CHAMP CLASS POSITION where the results should look like this

```
CAR|CLASS|CLASS FINISH POSITION|CHAMP CLASS POSITION
1  |5    |1                    |1
2  |1    |1                    |1
3  |2    |2                    |1
4  |     |                     |
5  |3    |3                    |1
6  |5    |2                    |2
7  |     |                     |
8  |2    |5                    |2
9  |5    |                     |
10 |5    |8                    |3
```

with this formula:

```
=IF(C2>0,SUMPRODUCT((B2=$B$2:$B$28)*(C2>$C$2:$C$28))+1,"")
```

I end up with the CHAMP CLASS POSITION like this:

```
CAR|CLASS|CLASS FINISH POSITION|CHAMP CLASS POSITION
1  |5    |1                    |2
2  |1    |1                    |1
3  |2    |2                    |1
4  |     |                     |
5  |3    |3                    |1
6  |5    |2                    |3
7  |     |                     |
8  |2    |5                    |2
9  |5    |                     |
10 |5    |8                    |4
```

because car 9 in class 5 did not finish and has no class result it bumps all class 5 positions by 1.

Is there a way to tweak the formula to exclude any results where class finish position is BLANK?

Obviously I can delete the class cell for car 9 for it to work, but this sheet would be used for multiple events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=IF(C2>0,SUMPRODUCT((B2=$B$2:$B$28)*(C2>$C$2:$C$28)*($C$2:$C$28<>""))+1,"")
```

should be enough to ignore empty cells

but you can also do it as a COUNTIFS:-

```
=IF(C2>0,COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$28,B2,$C$2:$C$28,"<"&C2,$C$2:$C$28,"<>"&"")+1,"")
```

Comment: the countif also works like this: `=IF(C2>0,COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$28,B2,$C$2:$C$28,"<"&C2)+1,"")` (no need for the not empty check)

Comment: while `is` and `is not` works with every value, `"<"` and `">"` will be skipped for all non numerical cells (they will not be counted). but that is for countifs, most other functions will act like an empty cell is zero, while an empty string `=""` will still be text (can be tested with the original formula, if entered `=""` in `C10` the calculation will be correct) ;)